# Stuck Preview Image on Dragging and Dropping a File on a FileDropTarget

Tags: python, python-2.7, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I'm working on a document management system right now and am trying to implement a Drag and Drop feature, which lets the user drag a file from the windows explorer into my program.

For that I created my own custom Drop Target:

```
class DocumentsDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):

    """Implements the ability to import a new document/file as a DB File
    by drag and drop.
    See for more info: http://wiki.wxpython.org/DragAndDrop"""

    def __init__(self, parent, import_as_db_file_method):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.import_as_db_file_method = import_as_db_file_method

    def OnDropFiles(self, dummy_x, dummy_y, files):
        """Makes sure that only one file is dropped. Then translates the
        dropped file into source_folder and filename and then calls the
        method for importing the file as a db file."""
        if len(files) != 1:
            show_error_message(self.parent,
                               "Documents", "MOnlyOneFilePerDBImport")
            return
        source_path = files[0]
        split_position = string.rfind(source_path, '\\')
        source_folder = source_path[:split_position]
        filename = source_path[(split_position + 1):]
        self.import_as_db_file_method(source_folder=source_folder,
                                      filename=filename)
```

This works perfectly. My program picks up the right source_folder and filename and imports correctly the new file.

The problem is only that inside the method `self.import_as_db_file_method(...)` is a dialog, which will be shown to the user before the actual import, to be able to set some options for the import.

While that Dialog is open you can't use the windows explorer and the preview image of the dragging process is stuck on my screen. After pressing the button 'Importieren' the method `self.import_as_db_file_method(...)` finishes and the stuck preview image disappears.

Is there any way I can tell the windows explorer that I collected all data I needed and finish the dragging process before calling `self.import_as_db_file_method(...)`

Example of the stuck preview image over my Dialog:
[image: DragAndDrop Stuck Preview Image Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure of what your problem is but in the past when using `wx.FileDropTarget` I code it to set a global variable with the tested and cleaned up filename, then I use a `wx.Timer` once a second to test the global variable.
Whilst this does involve an overhead, it does mean that the drop and drag has finished and the file has been tested for type etc by the time I access the file for whatever I intend to do with it, within the `wx.Timer` code.

Comment: Thanks, the timer helped. I just started the timer on dropping a file and stopped it before calling `self.import_as_db_file_method(...)` in the timer called function. Through that I don't need a constantly running timer.

Comment: @JonnyTieM Glad it helped. That's an interesting option that you used.